# program to calculate the time

Tags: perl, perl-module

I would like to calculate the the current time and add 2 minutes to it and print the output in the following format. HH:MM . I searched online and came to know that  there are lot of CPAN modules that can be used to implement this. But I'd like to do it without cpan modules.

```
  $current_time = time();

  $new_time  = $current_time + (2*60); // adding  two minutes 

  print( ' the time is ' .  $ new_time  ) ;

 Output : the time is 1424906904
```

I searched online and came to know that we need to use POSIX perl interface to print the time in the appropriate format.  However i'd like to know if there is a way to do this without using any cpan modules.

Comment: POSIX isn't a CPAN module. It's a standard module. It's been included as part of the Perl distribution forever (ok, for about twenty years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy to do with [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html).  Hours, minutes, and seconds are the 2nd, 1st, and 0th values returned.  For example:

```
my ($sec, $min, $hours) = localtime(time()+120); # add 120 seconds

printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n", $hours, $min, $sec;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html):

```
print scalar localtime($current_time);
```

Or you can run `localtime`'s return values through [`POSIX::strftime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX#strftime) (which is distributed with Perl as a core module):

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

print strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime $current_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) have been included with all Perl installations since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $time = localtime;
$time += 2 * ONE_MINUTE;

say $time->strftime('%H:%M');
```